# take a screenshot from a .264 or .m2ts file

Tags: java, video, encoding, screenshot, h.264

How i can get a screenshot (png, jpg) from a .264 or .m2ts file in java?

I try to write a wrapper for ffmepeg. It's not a good solution.

Maybe someone know a good libary?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used ffmpeg by ProcessBuilder class

Answer (score 0):

Use the Robot class with the CreateScreenCapture() method.  This can be used to create screenshots.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
```

Also, use the ImageIO.write() static method to save the BufferedImage object to a file:

```
ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("Screenshot"+" .jpg"));
```

Comment: i want take a screenshot from a video file, not from the desktop